# Most Efficient Alternative Method of Storing Settings for iPhone Apps

Tags: iphone, optimization, core-data, settings, settings.bundle

I am not using the Settings bundle to store the settings for my app, as I prefer to allow the user to access the settings within the app (they may be changed fairly often). I do realize that there is the option to do both, but for now, I am trying to find the most optimal place to store the settings within the app.

I have a good number of settings (from what I have read, probably too many for NSUserDefaults), and the two main options I am considering are:
1) storing the settings in a dictionary in the plist, loading the settings into a NSDictionary property in the app delegate and accessing them via the sharedDelegate
2) storing the settings in a Core Data entity (1 row on Settings entity), loading the settings into a Settings object in the app delegate and accessing them via the sharedDelegate

Of these two, which would be the optimal method, performance wise?

Comment: Too many for `NSDefaults`? If you have a thousand keys, then, probably, yes. But then you're doing your settings wrong.

Comment: If you do not want to use NSUserDefaults with a large amount of settings why not create an object that contains all the settings, make it conform to the NSCoding protocol, save it on app terminate/resigns active and load it on application didFinishLaunching?

Comment: If you store much data forget about all the "use `[ud synchronize]`!!1111one"-Answers you have seen on stackoverflow. They are usually wrong anyway. Just don't call synchronize after every `setObject:forKey:` and you won't have any problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use NSUserDefaults, that is what it is there for. Why do you feel like you have too many for it?

Also, if you decide to use the settings bundle later, you'll need to use NSUserDefaults anyway.

Comment: Is it really a lot better performance wise than the above two options? Is there any case (or number of settings) in which either of the above two would be better? I've been reading these boards pretty extensively and I *think* I saw something from Marcus Zarra saying the sometimes storing the settings in Core Data was more optimal, but I don't know which thread it was in (and I don't think he explained *when* it was more optimal)

Comment: I really don't see any situation where you would be accessing the defaults enough for any performance gain to be noticeable. Also, NSUserDefaults is really just a plist anyway, you would end up implementing something that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

You should go with NSUserDefaults only. If you think there are lot of NSUserDefaults I Suggest you to create 1 model class and go with it. Create one model class and have your settings as properties and create object of that class and save it to NSUserDefaults will be easy for you as it is one time implementation only.

```
@interface SettingsModelClass : NSObject 
{
    NSString *strSetting1;
    BOOL boolSetting2;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strSetting1;
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL boolSetting2;
```

//Implementaiton

```
@implementation SettingsModelClass

@synthesize strSetting1, boolSetting2;

-(void)dealloc
{
    [strSetting1 release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    //Encode properties, other class variables, etc
    [encoder encodeObject:self.strSetting1 forKey:@"StringSetting"];    
    [encoder encodeBool:self.boolSetting2 forKey:@"BoolSetting"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if( self != nil )
    {
        //decode properties, other class vars
        self.strSetting1 = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"StringSetting"]; 
        self.boolSetting2 = [decoder decodeBoolForKey:@"BoolSetting"]; 
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Please leave comments if you have any doubt. I would love to help you.

**Update**
Yes you would access through application delegate. Or even you can create it as singleton class instance. 
This approach is using OOPS fundas so it is batter to follow this pattern that I believe.

Comment: This looks great - at what point (i.e. how many settings) does this method become advantageous over using straight-up NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Also, would I load the settings into the SettingsModelClass object in the app delegate and access them via the sharedDelegate throughout the app? If not, how would I load/access the settings in the various view controllers throughout the app?

Comment: Thank you - but would this be slower than just using NSUserDefaults directly?

Comment: thanks for the info; this is something I would like to try in the future; for now I have decided to just use NSUserDefaults directly